# Snowflake JDBC Connection using Talend

Tags: jdbc, connection, talend, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using tDBConnection(JDBC) component to connect with a snowflake.
After all the setup I am getting the below error

```
    net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest execute
    SEVERE: Stop retrying since elapsed time due to network issues has reached 
    timeout. Elapsed: 71,253(ms), timeout: 60,000(ms)
    Exception in component tDBConnection_1 (sf_test)
java.lang.RuntimeException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: Certificate for <xxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com, *.global.snowflakecomputing.com, *.sg.ap-southeast-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com].
    at snowflake_poc.sf_test_0_1.sf_test.tDBConnection_1Process(sf_test.java:397)
    at snowflake_poc.sf_test_0_1.sf_test.runJobInTOS(sf_test.java:700)
    at snowflake_poc.sf_test_0_1.sf_test.main(sf_test.java:550)
```

I am using latest snowflake JDBC driver 3.12.2

Any leads would be really helpful

Thanks

Comment: This could be an OCSP issue. Please refer to this section of the documents discussing it https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/ocsp.html. You may want to try setting the JDBC driver to ocsp_fail_open=true. If that's not it, have your network team see if there's a firewall or proxy (such as from Cisco or Palo Alto) performing packet inspection. Sometimes they get confused with where HTTPS traffic is valid to connect and drop packets. If that's the problem, the network team may need to change settings to allow the traffic.

Comment: In addition to the above networking checks, you'll want to make sure your Snowflake account is reachable from the Talend server.  If there are any IP Whitelist policies in place on Snowflake, that'll create these types of issues, as well.

Comment: These are great suggestions - they would also make great answers (in my opinion).

Comment: Add snowflake certificate

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue, in the Talend account box just give your account name alond which is "<xxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-1" don't postfix snowflakecomputing.com to your account name